# Declaring a structure and immediately instantiating it with cv-qualifier or storage duration specifier

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
static const struct X
{
    int a;
} x={1};

X y;
```

It compiles, and `X` appears to work in the declaration of `y`. But is it actually true that `static const` and similar cv-qualifiers and storage duration specifiers don't affect the definition of `X`? I.e. is the following exactly equivalent to the above?

```
struct X
{
    int a;
};
static const X x={1};

X y;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name `X`  in declaration

```
static const struct X
{
    int a;
} x={1};
```

introduces type specifier `struct X`. Thus this declaration

```
X y;
```

is equivalent to

```
struct X y;
```

As for storage class specifiers then according to the C++ Standard (7.1.1 Storage class specifiers)

> 1. ... The storage-class-specifier applies to the name declared by each init-declarator in the list and not to any names declared by other specifiers.

So in this declaration

```
static const struct X
{
    int a;
} x={1};
```

static is a storage class specifier of declarator `x` that is present in init-declarator `x={1}`

If you would use for example a typedef

```
typedef const struct
{
    int a;
} X;
```

then in this case type name `X` would indeed have qualifier const.

So if you will define for example

```
X x = { 1 };
```

then x will be a constant object. You will be unable to write

```
x.a = 2;
```

Nevertheless you may not specify a storage class specifier in a typedef because as it is said in the quote storage class specifiers may be specified only for init-declarators.
However you may write

```
static X x = { 1 };
```

because the storage class specifier is applied to `x` that has type `const X`